# Fill missing values in a sorted collection

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, generics

I wrote a generic function to find and fill the missing values in a sequence, I have few classes which implements IColumnData so I intend to pass the collection of the class and expect the missing data filled in it

```
Private Function FillMissingData(Of T As {IColumnData, New})(data As IEnumerable(Of T), valueFunc As Func(Of Integer, Double)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Dim range As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
    Dim current As IEnumerable(Of T) = data
    If current.Count() < range.Count() Then
        Dim missingPeriods As IEnumerable(Of Integer) = range.Except(data.Select(Function(d) d.Column))
        Dim missingData As IEnumerable(Of T)
        missingData = missingPeriods.Select(Function(column) New T() With {.Column = column, .Value = valueFunc(column)})
        current = data.Union(missingData).OrderBy(Function(r) r.Column)
    End If
    Return current
End Function
```

The function is working fine but I am not satisfied with the code, it look like a mess, also the performance is poor if the range is large. this piece of code is expected to work for approx 100K views per day via an aspx page.

I am looking for some solution specific to this piece of code.

Comment: This might be worth asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since you seem to be asking for a code review. Not sure if it is off topic here as such but it is certainly on topic there and might get you other answers.

Comment: Could you perhaps create a data collection that encapsulates your data and does this transformation on request (rather than having to call this function explicitly. It would seem neater to me but I don't know if it would be practical for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your data is already sorted by `Column`, you can improve the performance with an iterator method like this:

```
Private Iterator Function FillMissingData(Of T As {IColumnData, New})(data As IEnumerable(Of T), valueFunc As Func(Of Integer, Double)) As IEnumerable(Of T)
    Dim nextExpectedColumn = 1
    Dim maxColumn = 10
    For Each element As T In data
        'Yield the missing elements
        For column As Integer = nextExpectedColumn To element.Column - 1
            Yield New T() With {.Column = column, .Value = valueFunc(column)}
        Next
        Yield element
        nextExpectedColumn = element.Column + 1
    Next
    For column As Integer = nextExpectedColumn To maxColumn
        Yield New T() With {.Column = column, .Value = valueFunc(column)}
    Next
End Function
```

For an unordered data set the `Except` method is potentially slow because it requires additional memory for a `HashSet`. Furthermore, ordering the new set is `O(n log n)`. The above method has linear time complexity but requires the input data to be sorted.

Comment: Thanks @nico, it looks promising, I'll run the tests tonight to verify the same.

Comment: Hi @nico, the results are impressive too, I am able to see a significant difference of approx 28% decrease in average load time with 500 virtual users on test and variable max columns till 3500. Thanks for the solution, it's clean and it is efficient too.